# python back reference from regex like perl

Tags: python, regex

in perl you can do

```
if (/(.*)__(.*)/) {
   print "ans" . $1 . ' ' . $2 . "\n";
}
```

in python, can you do the same?
It seems like you can only do

```
m = re.match(r"(.*)__(.*),data)
if m:
   print("ans {} {}".format(m[1],m[2])
```

Or is there better way to do this in more pythonic way?

Anyway, if this is the way to go, then it's gonna really suck if you have lot of big if and elif to test against many different possible patterns. 
I am really hoping someone who is more familiar w/ python can enlighten me

in perl

```
if (/(.*)__(.*)/){
   #do another
} elsif ( /(.*)XXX___(.*)/) {
   #do one thing
}
......
```

Imagine I have many test cases. In python, how would I do that?

Comment: as far as I know, Python doesn't have global variables that automatically get set with regex matching groups, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637592/perl-like-regex-in-python

Comment: regarding downvotes, that just seems to be the trend on `regex` tag

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311708/python-equivallent-of-perl-match-and-capture-within-if-block

Comment: much appreciate this post.. I was really hoping I could write this portion in python as I am learning and thought this was a great opportunity.. but this is bit too cumbersome.. will have to write this part in perl. thank you!